# using .htaccess file to denying certain file types

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i want implementing `.htaccess` in a way such that my certain file types like `.js` or `.css` can not be opened through direct access like `www.example.com/path/to/style.css`. this should be a 403 error, however browser can be able to read this file if requires.

here is the code i implemented and this works on local server but not when i uploaded my page to main server

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?127.0.0.1 [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?127.0.0.1.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpg|png)$ - [F]
```

EDIT:
i just made an attempt and tried this and it worked for me!

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?127.0.0.1 [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?127.0.0.1.*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpg|png)$ - [F]
```

this was much easier than i was thinking and credit to my thinking also goes to [Andy Holmes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477407/andy-holmes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer i come with, adding mydomain.com as another domain, and literally you can add as many domain as you want and can add same .htaccess of each apache server

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?127.0.0.1 [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?127.0.0.1.*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpg|png)$ - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?127.0.0.1.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain.com.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(png|jpg|jpeg|css|js)$ - [F,NS,L]
```

Give this a go, is my only other suggestion

Comment: sorry but this is allowing the given file types by direct access

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/images/*\.jpg$
RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/images/*\.jpeg$
RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/images/*\.png$
RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/styles/*\.css$
RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/js/*\.js$
```

I don't know how you've structured your folders etc but try this, obviously change to suit your folder structure. It should allow for images to be shown on the site, but not directly accessed

Comment: Any luck on this one?

Comment: Ah that makes sense, any chance of an upvote on my earlier answer? Looks like a combo of both yours and mine :)

Comment: Much appreciated. Helpful tip - post your working code as your own answer and accept that, it'll help future viewers :)

Answer (score -1):

Change 127.0.0.1 to your domain name

EDIT:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?:js|css|jpg|png|jpg|jpeg)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

EDIT2:

I misunderstood you

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?{HTTP_HOST} [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: this isn't working, i tried and this just flooded my console with 403

Comment: That's because it's exactly the same as my answer. Working on another for you

Comment: edit2 is also not working. I can't figure out why my own js are working but not bootstrap.min.js from twitter. and still it is not preventing direct opening.